# iOS Swift Timer sometimes fires much later than expected

Tags: ios, swift, timer, nstimer

Creating a 10 minute timer. It always works for me on multiple phones and iOS versions. Timer fires  at 10 minutes. I have a user report that their timer fires at much longer interval, 14-18 minutes. What could cause this behavior? This is running as part of a regular iOS UIKit based app.

User with the issue is running iOS 17.3.1 on iPhone 14 Pro.

The call to `startLockout` is being performed on the main thread.

Code generally as follows:

```
class Manager {
    static let shared = Manager()

    var timers: Set<Timer> = []

    func startLockout() {
        let timerLengthInSeconds: Double  = 60 * 10
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timerLengthInSeconds,target: self,
                                     selector:#selector(resetLockout),
                                     userInfo: nil,
                                      repeats: false)
        timers.insert(timer)
    }

    @objc func resetLockout(for: Any) {
         print("Time: \(Date())")
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with having your app in the background if you haven't already.

Comment: Why try in background? It needs to at least work in foreground and always works for me at 10 minutes. I've tried with background refresh off for the phone. We don't normally request background mode in the app. It still works as I'd expect. I am out of ideas what could be different on this user's phone.

Comment: I mean you should test to let the app run in the background and see if that delays the timer the way the user has reported, not that you should change the code.

Comment: If you need accuracy, use the one [from GCD] timer(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsourcetimer)

Answer (score 1):

While there is some variance that can take place as a result of “timer coalescing” (which can be fixed by using a “strict” gcd timer, or changing the [`tolerance`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1415085-tolerance) of the `Timer`), that is unlikely the problem here.

As Joakim suggested, if the timer is really firing minutes later, that’s more than can generally be accounted for by mere timer coalescing. The more likely problem is that the app was suspended when the user left it to do something else. When the app is suspended, no timers will fire until the user relaunches the app. (And you cannot keep an app running perpetually in the background; when the user leaves the app, execution will be suspended.)

As a word of caution, do not test this “what happens when the user leaves the app” scenario while debugging with Xcode. The Xcode debugger can artificially keep the app running in the background even if the user leaves the app on the device. Do your tests while launching the app from the device itself, not running it attached to the debugger.

Assuming this is the case, if you want the user to be notified even if they left the app and the app was suspended, you would reach for the [UserNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications) framework. Your app may be suspended, but the OS will present a user notification at the appointed time.

So, let’s say that a user started a 10 minute timer and left the app. Rather than relying on the `Timer` (which will not fire when the app is suspended), you would schedule a user notification for the appointed time. That way, even if your app is not active, the OS will present a user notification at the appointed time. The user will either dismiss the alert, or tap on it to activate the app. But either way, they’ll know that 10 minutes have passed.

See WWDC 2021 video [Send communication and Time Sensitive notifications](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10091/).

Comment: For the sake of completeness, it should be noted that the other thing that can cause timers to not fire is if you have something blocking the main thread. Using dispatch semaphore or dispatch group `wait` is a common source of these sorts of problems. That having been said, that’s unlikely the case here, as blocking the main thread for that long usually leads for more catastrophic problems (like a frozen UI, the OS watchdog process summarily killing your app, etc.). But I mention this as another (unlikely) edge-case for timers not firing at the intended time.

Comment: Also, if the user “force quits” the app, that will also prevent timers (and notifications) from firing. Again, this is unlikely to be the problem here (as that would keep them from firing at all), but it is another edge case to be aware of.

Comment: Thanks. The failing user is one of our remote testers and they claim the app was kept in foreground the entire time. They even included a Quicktime screen recording of the process. I've tested quicktime recording as well and it didn't seem to affect the timer in my tests.

Even if it were suspended, wouldn't it run as soon as it went back to foreground assuming 10 minutes had passed? This is a lockout timer that prevents a user hitting a button for 10 minutes. But they keep trying the button and released 14-18 minutes later, not 10.

Comment: Turns out Joakim and Rob are right. I let the phone timeout and lock. The in app timer was delayed firing roughly by the amount of time the phone was locked (-1 min). 
Whats the best way to schedule a timer? I had assumed it wasn't a busy wait that required being active, but a scheduled time. Does a GCD timer behave differently?

Comment: The idea would be to invalidate timers (and schedule user notifications, if you want the user to be notified when the app is not running) in `applicationDidEnterBackground`, and then recreate them in `applicationWillEnterForeground`.